# Meaning of ポケモンをねかしつけていません

Tags: translation

Could somebody tell me what the Japanese text in the screengrab below says? Unfortunately, I do not know how to type it, so I've got it only as an image.

[image]

Comment: It says, ポケモンをねかしつけていません.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Google Translate translates that as "Pokemon does not Nekashitsuke". This is not sufficiently well translated.

Comment: Where is the screengrab ...

Comment: @Hammerite. Japanese Stack Exchange is not meant for translation requests. Please try other sites or use our Chat function for matters not belonging in the main site (like translations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know about Pokemon to translate this one. It literally means something like 'You have not got Pokemon to go to sleep'.

Comment: I would have guessed "You don't have any Pokémon resting (here)," actually.

Comment: I don't know Pokemon, so I can only guess. But ねかしつける means 'to put to bed, put to sleep'. Because there is an を here, it means there is an unmentioned subject, but it would probably mean 'you' in the context.